# Html/CSS Z:index Position:Relative Question

Tags: html, css

I have a table with many rows.

I want to have an on hover effect on the rows. When someone hovers over a row a popup div displays with some additonal information about that row.

I was planning on doing this with a div and on hover making the div visible/invisible.

Now my problem is with the html/css.

How do I make the table with a div that appears on hover but does not affect the look of the table.

I was thinking z index, with position relative. But I cannot get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `position:abolute; top: 10px; left: 20px; z-index: 1` for the `div` and `position: relative` for the `tr`. (top and left are only assumptions. use these for positioning the div relative to your row)

Relative positioning the row, holds it in the context. Absolute positioning the div makes its position absolute to its parent (here the row). If the row doesn't have relative the div would be positioned absolute to the `body` or an parent element which has set a `position`.

Comment: Nealry there with this. But when I put it into Firefox - it does not work.

  <table>
 <tr id="rowb" style="position:relative">
      <td><strong>Apple</strong></td>
   <td>Green</td>
   <td>Tasty</td>
   <div class="extra" style="position:absolute; z-index:1; ">
       <li>the Big Apple Tree</li>
   </div>
 </tr>

 <tr id="rowb" style="position:relative">
      <td><strong>Strawberry</strong></td>
   <td>Red</td>
   <td>Delicious</td>
   <div class="extra" style="position:absolute; z-index:1; ">
       <li>the Big Strawberry Bush</li>
   </div>
 </tr>

Comment: maybe you make an example at http://jsfiddle.net where we can have a closer look.

Comment: this seemed to do the trick. But making it look nice is messy. I just used fancybox in the end. It imposes a couple of clicks on the user - instead of a hover. But looks good and works well.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements have the same z-index then the browser will display them in the order they appear in the html. So you don't have to set z-index at all. You can do something like this ***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NsqS2/1/)***. (Hover over the top left cell, or the 3rd from top in the second column.) So long as the divs you want to display are below the table in which you wish to highlight.

Answer (score 0):

Is it important to use only html and css in your project ? If not you could handle the hover functionality over to Javascript.